# Input elements not scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css, typescript, ionic2

Ionic 2 input elements not scrolling to top when keyboard is shown. I have tried everything that i could find on google. making sure keyboard disable scroll is not true. But still couldn't figure it out what makes the scroll not working. 
Any advice would be helpful. Thank you.

**Code:**

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar color="header">
    <ion-title>Billing Info</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content>
  <ion-list style="padding: 10px 15% 10px 15%">
    <ion-item *ngFor="let item of cart.Food">
      {{item.Food}}
      <div item-right>₹ {{item.Qty*item.Price}}</div>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
  <ion-item (click)="toggleGroup(i)" style="padding: 10px 15% 10px 15%; font-size: large">
    Net Total
    <div item-right>₹ 150
      <ion-icon color="success" [name]="isGroupShown(i) ? 'arrow-dropdown' : 'arrow-dropright'"></ion-icon>
    </div>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-list *ngIf="isGroupShown(i)" style="padding: 10px 15% 10px 15%" [ngClass]="{active: isGroupShown(i)}">
    <ion-item>
      Bill Amount
      <div item-right>₹ 150</div>
    </ion-item>
    ...
  </ion-list>
  <ion-item style="padding: 10px 15% 10px 15%">
    <ion-label>Discounts</ion-label>
    <ion-checkbox item-right color="secondary" [(ngModel)]="discount" checked="false"></ion-checkbox>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-grid style="padding: 10px 15% 10px 15%; background-color: #f0e68c" radio-group [(ngModel)]="type">
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col col-6>
        <ion-item>
          <ion-label>Percentage</ion-label>
          <ion-radio value="percentage" checked item-right></ion-radio>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col col-6>
        <ion-item>
          <ion-label>Amount</ion-label>
          <ion-radio value="amount"></ion-radio>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col col-12>
        <ion-list>
          <ion-item>
            <ion-label floating>Unit</ion-label>
            <ion-input type="text"></ion-input>
          </ion-item>
          <ion-item>
            <ion-label floating>Reason</ion-label>
            <ion-textarea rows="5"></ion-textarea>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col col-12>
        <button ion-button>Apply</button>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
</ion-content>
<ion-footer text-center>
  <ion-toolbar position="bottom">
    <button ion-button color="cart" round large outline>BILL</button>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-footer>
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is a topic for this kind of issue on [ionic forum](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/keyboard-attach-in-ionic-2/49635). Did You read it?

There are workarounds like those:

1. Using a regular `<input type="text">` instead of `<ion-input type="text">`
2. Using some custom directive to make element "attached" to keyboard: https://gist.github.com/Manduro/bc121fd39f21558df2a952b39e907754